# Durandal- Uncaught Error: History has already been activated

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, durandal

In my project, i have a login screen, then few navigation pages and logout. Once i logout and try to login again i get an error: Uncaught Error: History has already been activated.

How should i deactivate history on every logout?

I have added deactivate method in all pages and have been setting the views view models to null. What are the things i need to take care of on logout? Any code sample would be helpful.

In main.js i have the following code:

```
define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator', 'plugins/router'],
    function (system, app, viewLocator, router) {

        system.debug(true);

        app.configurePlugins({
            router: true
        });

        app.start().then(function () {

            viewLocator.useConvention();

            app.setRoot('viewmodels/login');

            system.log('Main Module started');
        });


    });
```

On successful login, i am setting the app root to shell. the code in shell.js is as follows:

```
define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/system', 'durandal/app'], function (router, system, app) {
    return {
        title: 'Configuration',
        router: router,
        activate: function () {

            system.log('Configuring routes');

            router.map([
                {
                    route: '', moduleId: 'viewmodels/home', nav: true,
                    title: 'Home'
                },
                {
                    route: 'a1', moduleId: 'viewmodels/a1', nav: true,
                    title: 'A1'
                },
                {
                    route: 'a2', moduleId: 'viewmodels/a2', nav: true,
                    title: 'a2'
                }

            ]).buildNavigationModel();

            system.log('Shell view activating');


            return router.activate();
        },

        logout: function () {
            app.setRoot('viewmodels/login');
        },

        deactivate: function () {

            router.deactivate();
            router = null;
            console.log("shell js- deactivate.. ");
        },


    }
});
```

In method deactivate- i m setting the router to null.

What should be done to solve this probem?

Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering, why do you need to deactivate the router? Personally, I've never done it and the documentation doesn't mention deactivation in the router section. Looking at the code, the following comment is present on the `rootRouter.deactivate` function: `Disable history, perhaps temporarily. Not useful in a real app, but possibly useful for unit testing Routers.`

Comment: Consider using `window.location.reload()` on logout. That will start the SPA from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, yes it seems that you have to call router.deactivate(). Here's what I have on my page when trying to do something similar so far:

```
function login() {
    router.reset();
    router.deactivate();
    app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');
}
```

Without the deactivate I get the error, with it I don't. I thought reset or nulling the router would have worked but didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and found that the reason was that I was calling `.activate()` method after mapping the route [ I mean call *`activate()`* in some where other than ***shell.js***].

In summery i can tell that just **remove** that *`.activate()`* if you have it in any where other than **shell.js**